# Oracle how to export a whole table

Tags: python, sql, oracle, performance, oracle12c

Description

We have to read an entire table (Oracle 12c), export the data, process them, and re import the processed data into another software. We are doing it using python with the python-cx_Oracle library.

The table contains ~2milions rows. There are 6 columns: a primary key some varchars and 2 CLOB columns

Tried solutions:

1. `SELECT * FROM <TABLE> ORDER BY ID ASC OFFSET <X> ROWS FETCH NEXT 2000 ROWS ONLY;`
   This is is working but it is pretty slow (~ 30 seconds every time we have to perform it changing OFFSET
2. `SELECT * FROM <TABLE> OFFSET <X> ROWS FETCH NEXT 2000 ROWS ONLY;`
   We tried this one (without the ordering) and is a lot faster, but with the time the performance degraded from < 1 sec to < 10 seconds per query. Also I am not sure that without the ordering ALL the rows are going to be exported considering that another application is continuing inserting data into the table.
3. Same query as point 2) but executing multiple exports in parallel:

   - From 0 to 500k rows
   - From 500k to 1mil
   - From 1mil to 1.5mil
   - From 1.5mil up to the end of the table (assessed with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <TABLE>` just before evaluating the exit condition of the loop)

   With this solution we noticed some improvements but still after some time the performance degraded from ~1000 rows/s to ~250 rows/s descending

Questions

- Is there a way to optimize the point 3?
- Is there any other better way that I am missing?
- If we export the data without the ordering by ID, am I totally sure that ALL the data will be exported considering that there are new records added every seconds?

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to select batches of rows in the first place? How is the performance if you just select all rows `SELECT * FROM <TABLE>` and process them one by one?

Comment: @doberkofler we thought about batches because we want to parallelize the ingestion in the other software in order to improve the performances. After we fetch the data we do some manipulation and then we call a rest api to ingest the oracle data into another software. This operations can be done in parallel

Comment: @Fabry I understand, but could you not just create the batches programmatically when selecting the rows from the Oracle table? Your post suggests that the Oracle select ist „the“ bottleneck and you want to improve its performance.

Comment: @doberkofler, I'll try and let you know. One question, if I use `SELECT * FROM <TABLE>` what will happen if while I am parsing the data, new rows will be added in the table? Will they be fetched automatically by the db cursor ? or I have to do some sort of cross checking at the end and see which rows are missing?

Comment: While processing the rows you will exactly see the rows (without insert, update or delete) at the point in time when the select was issued. If you want to see what happened to the table in the meantime, you need some separate logic that will most likely need some additional column.

Comment: @jarlh I checked the link you posted as well and I see some improvements. Thank you

Comment: What is your `cursor.arraysize` value? Tuning this can significantly improve fetch performance.  See the cx_Oracle documentation [Tuning cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html).

Comment: *"process them"* - what processing are you doing? Oracle SQL is incredibly powerful. There's a good chance you can encapsulate all this in a single action: querying, transforming and exporting in one SELECT statement